# Unable to post to bitbucket using OAuth2Session and requests_oauthlib in python

Tags: python-2.7, post, oauth-2.0, python-requests, bitbucket

I have a python script that auto refreshes and gets a new access token to access bitbucket end points.

My script works as long as it a 'GET' request. I am trying to do a post to create a private repository inside a private project. But I am getting a 400 status code which means my request is malformed.

For eg:

`protected_url='https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/<team>'
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
client = OAuth2Session(client_id, token=token, auto_refresh_url=refresh_url,auto_refresh_kwargs=extra, token_updater=token_saver)
token=client.refresh_token(refresh_url, **extra)
token_saver(token)
client = OAuth2Session(client_id, token=token)
r = client.get(protected_url)
print r.content`

works and fetches the list of repositories in bitbucket but

```
    data1={"scm": "git", "is_private": "true", "fork_policy": "no_public_forks", "project": {"key": "project_key"}}
data=json.dumps(data1)
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
protected_url='https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/<team>/<new_repo>'

    from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
    client = OAuth2Session(client_id, token=token, auto_refresh_url=refresh_url,auto_refresh_kwargs=extra, token_updater=token_saver)
    token=client.refresh_token(refresh_url, **extra)
    token_saver(token)
    client = OAuth2Session(client_id, token=token)
    r=client.post(protected_url, data=data, headers=headers)
    print r.content
```

gives a 400 status code(the request is malformed) with the error

> '{"type": "error", "error": {"message": "Private projects cannot
>   contain public repositories"}}'

. I have the access token to authenticate, my URIs are correct, it is just the syntax of the post request that looks incorrect. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: I have recently run into the exact same situation and have yet to find a solution.  Were you ever able to solve this?'

Comment: For what it's worth, this was working for me: curl -u "xxx:yyy" -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "scm": "git",
    "project": {
        "key": "AB"
    },
    "is_private" : "true"
}' https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/zzz/hablanding